# JSLint showing incorrect line numbers in console

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jslint

I am using Grunt JSlint module to check lint error in javascript files. it is working perfectly but if there is any error in the file, it is showing incorrect line number.

```
line 2718  col 4  Missing semicolon.  (W033)
```

actual line number 2716, is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you show your grunt-jslint config?

Comment: Need more information. Is it always off by two? Can you make a simplest case file with one line and a JSLint mistake? Does it say 3? Can you post a screenshot of the file you mention with the surrounding code? Perhaps there's also a mistake on 2716? etc etc etc